# How can i disable the build notification for bitbucket in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I ran into a problem, while using this snippet on a Multibranch Pipeline

```
if (currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().toString().contains('BranchIndexingCause')) {
  print "INFO: Build skipped due to trigger being Branch Indexing"
  currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED' // optional, gives a better hint to the user that it's been skipped, rather than the default which shows it's successful
  return
}

pipeline{
........
```

While the code itself is doing its job just fine and aborting the build i still get

```
[Bitbucket] Notifying pull request build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
```

I want to skip bitbucket notify, because whenever the previous build is successful this piece of code will make it appear as it is failed, thus creating a confusion..

How can i leave the last result on display in Bitbucket

Isn't this snippet aborting the build before it even runs due to its placement in the Jenkinsfile

Comment: I am a little bit confused... do you want the build to start but then cancel it? Or do you want the build to not start at all? Those would be two different approaches. And no, that code snipet does not avoid the build to start

Comment: did you find the answer to this question?